# Help with shell script - Rename filenames (remove special chars) in a directory?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a directory of csv files with spaces and all kinds of characters. How do I rename them? The following gives an error.

```
#! /bin/bash

cd DirectoryName

for file in *.csv; do
    #echo $file
    filename=${file%.*}
    file_clean=${filename//[ ()$+&\.\-\'\,]/_}
    final= "$file_clean.csv"
    mv "$file" $final
done

cd ..
```

Thanks!

UPDATE : (This works)

```
#! /bin/bash

cd DirectoryName

for file in *.csv; do
    #echo $file
    filename=${file%.*}
    file_clean=${filename//[ ()$+&\.\-\'\,]/_}
    final= "$file_clean.csv"
    mv "$file" $final
done

cd ..
```

Comment: the error message will probably help

Comment: bash : filename not a command error... fixed now! Thanks!

Comment: The updated version appears to be identical to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does. You're not quoting the substitutions, and your assignment to `$final` is incorrect. Quote all usages of substitution, and remove the space after the equal sign.

Comment: You sir, are a master :) Never realised a space will mess it up!